# Generate ppt slides from Sharepoint data

Tags: excel, powerpoint

There is a form in SharePoint and I need to generate an one page Powerpoint slide using some data from that Sharepoint list. I'm thinking about creating a template in Powerpoint. Let's say there will be 5 blocks in this template and there are "name", "surname", etc. sections in SharePoint list. I want to import this "name" to one of the blocks and so on. All of the data are text. Is writing such a program possible? If so, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the OpenXML SDK. For more info see Chapter 10 of Ed Hild's book,You can find more info in the book [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhild/archive/2006/12/03/pro-sharepoint-solution-development-combining-net-sharepoint-and-office-2007.aspx)